how to store recorded video on sd card via pi zero family non wireless
I have a pi zero non wireless board , can i record videos in 1080p through v3 camera and store the recorded video directly on sd card ?
if so ,how can i do it..

have you tried any of the solutions if you search raspberry pi record video to sd card in the search engine of your choice?
